# When is the tensor product of two graphs planar?

Tags: graph-theory

Given two graphs $G=(V_1,E_1)$ and $H=(V_2,E_2)$, the tensor product of $G$ and $H$ is the graph $G \times H = (V,E)$, where $V=V_1 \times V_2$ is the Cartesian product of the $V_i$ and 
$ (u,v) \ E \ (u',v') \Leftrightarrow u E_1 u' \wedge v E_2 v'$.

Is anyone aware of a characterization of which $G,H$ give rise to a planar tensor product $G \times H$?

Comment: Do you mean $(u,v) \ E \ (u',v') \Leftrightarrow u E_1 u' \wedge v E_2 v'$ (or, equivalently, $v$ and $u$ in $(u,v) \ E \ (u',v') \Leftrightarrow u E_1 u' \wedge v E_2 v'$)?

Comment: Yes, excuse the sloppiness. Fixed.

Comment: I'm no graph theorist. And probably you already know this, but Exercises 5.15-5.17 on pages 59 and 60 of the Handbook of Product Graphs (2nd edition) seem to characterize such $G$ and $H$ for some special cases.

Comment: Also, because a recent paper published in 2009 (https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00387303/document) that deals with this question has only 3 citations on google scalar (none of which seem to solve this problem), and also because the handbook published in 2011 doesn't have a complete solution to this seemingly natural question, it's likely still open, although you should ask a graph theorist to be sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yuichiro Fujiwara's comments seem to answer the question in full so I am making it an answer.  I quote below from [Kronecker products and local joins of graphs](http://cms.math.ca/cjm/v29/cjm1977v29.0255-0269.pdf) by M. Farzan and D. A. Waller, *Can. J. Math.* **29** (1977), 255–269.

> By a *1-contraction* of $G$ we mean the removal from $G$ of each vertex of degree 1 (and its incident edge).
>
> 5.3 THEOREM.  Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be connected graphs with more than four vertices.  Then $G_1\times G_2$ is planar if and only if either
>
> (i) one of the graphs is a path and the other one is 1-contractible to a path or a circuit, or
>
> (ii) one of them is a circuit and the other is 1-contractible to a path.

This leaves open only the case in which at least one of the graphs has fewer than five vertices.  Proposition 5.4, which I won't bother reproducing here, covers some of these cases.  [Beaudou et al.](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00387303/document) addresses the case $G=K_2$.  A complete solution appears to be still an open problem.